# Problematic wording/categorization on closed question notice

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60497715/passing-a-const-member-variable-to-an-external-function-c) (just for example) has been closed. The top of the page says:

> Closed. This question is off-topic. It is not currently accepting
>   answers.
>
> Edit the question to include desired behavior, a specific problem or
>   error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. This
>   will help others answer the question.

Well, the second paragraph is the actual reason the question was closed. But - a partial/missing reproducible/verifiable example doesn't make a question off-topic.

Can this wording be changed? And - is this a site-specific issue or a network issue?

Comment: The *missing reproducible/verifiable example* is under the off-topic section when closing so this is logical. If we have to change something, we should do it for the closure popup first.

Comment: The per-site close reasons all go under "off-topic" regardless of whether that actually makes sense. Given how they've ignored a lot of community feedback to other recent changes to the close dialog and messages and that they can't even do simple things like fix the "requires editing" button in Triage, I wouldn't count on this getting changed any time soon.

Comment: @TemaniAfif: While I'm sure I've seen that myself, my mind keeps forgetting that fact because it makes no sense. That, and the selection of alternative sites on the network which magically is never the site I want to suggest :-P